# What and when was the first gyroscopic flight instrument introduced?

Tags: gyroscopic-instruments

One of things which consistently amazes me about flight is the exceptional progress in the early decades of flight - especially in terms of avionics. Wikipedia tells me that the first ILS landing was in 1938.

I'd like to understand more about the early development of gyroscopic flight instruments - in particular, what the first instruments like? When were they first put to use?

Comment: The gyrocompass invention has been claimed by Sperry and Anschütz-Kaempfe for the naval industry. In 1914 both tried to sold one to the German navy, Anschütz-Kaempfe sued Sperry. [Einstein himself demonstrated to the German court](https://books.google.com/books?id=DN-9m2jSo8YC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36) that Anschütz-Kaempfe was right. Other litigations in the US and GB were lost. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope): "*The first functional gyrocompass was patented in 1904 by German inventor Hermann Anschütz-Kaempfe*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the first gyroscopic flight instrument in aviation was a gyroscopic stabilizer, with the purpose of [maintaining stability and control in a Curtiss C-2 biplane](http://flightclub.jalopnik.com/lawrence-sperry-inventor-of-the-autopilot-and-the-m-1592623110); it was first used (publicly) in 1914.

For this, the inventors, [Elmer A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elmer_Ambrose_Sperry) and [Lawrence B Sperry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Sperry) were awarded the Collier Trophy in 1914. Apparently [they did this](http://www.historynet.com/lawrence-sperry-autopilot-inventor-and-aviation-innovator.htm) by,

> ...linking the control surfaces with three gyroscopes, allowing flight corrections to be introduced based on the angle of deviation between the flight direction and the original gyroscopic settings.

[image: Stabilizer]

*Lawrence Sperry and gyroscopic stabilizer*, Image from wright-brothers.org

The device (with the gyroscopes spinning at 7000 rpm) was [first tested by Lawrence Sperry and Berringer](http://www.wright-brothers.org/History_Wing/History_of_the_Airplane/Decade_After/Girding_for_Battle/Girding_for_Battle.htm) on a Curtiss F aircraft in 1913, with the first public flight in 1914.

[image: First gyro flight]

*Sperry’s second flyby in Paris in the 1914 competition, with Emil on the wing*. Image from historicwings.com

Elmer [went on to develop](http://www.nationalaviation.org/sperry-sr-elmer/) the turn and bank indicator and an optical drift indicator, for which he was awarded the Collier trophy again in 1916.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that - what incredible engineering